# Is a Join clause somehow special?

Tags: sql-server, join, where-clause

When joining tables there are two ways, that are logically the same:

```
Select *
From tab1, tab2
Where tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

```
Select *
From tab1
Join tab2 On tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

You hear about join would perform better, but I don't think that that makes sense.
What scenario would make `join` special?

I understand `join` more as an easier to read version of parts of the where clause.

In fact you could even put conditions in the join that does not depend on the table its joins and still change the results. Which also indicates an extension of the where clause.

Comment: You may get a better answer on dba.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: Please read: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (Written 14 years ago...)